# Fire click on templated button

Tags: xaml, uwp

I want to create a custom button reveal template. I won't use `Style={ThemeResource ButtonRevealStyle}` for some reason. So, I've added ListViewItem inside button control template.

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="ButtonListView">
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget="True">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <ListViewItem>
                            <ContentPresenter></ContentPresenter>
                        </ListViewItem>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>


<Button Style="{ThemeResource ButtonListView}" Click="list_refresh">
    <TextBlock Text="Button Content"/>
</Button>
```

Illustration:
[image: Button template illustration]

But click event doesn't fire when I clicked on it. I think it fires on ListViewItem, not the button. And the most confusing thing is, it could fires using keyboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Fire click on templated button

As @Vincent said *ListViewItem is the first one to capture your click event*, for your scenario, we suggest you custom button reveal style and use  ListViewItem reveal theme resource. Or use Button `Tapped` event to replace.

For exampl:

```
<Style x:Key="CudtomButtonRevealStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemRevealBackground}" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonForeground}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemRevealBorderBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonRevealBorderThemeThickness}" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonPadding}" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" />
    <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="{StaticResource UseSystemFocusVisuals}" />
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualMargin" Value="-3" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid
                    x:Name="RootGrid"
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}">
                    <ContentPresenter
                        x:Name="ContentPresenter"
                        Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                        HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                        VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                        AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                        ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                        ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
                        CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}" />

                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal">

                                <Storyboard>
                                    <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>

                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="RootGrid.(RevealBrush.State)" Value="PointerOver" />
                                    <Setter Target="RootGrid.Background" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemRevealBackgroundPointerOver}" />
                                    <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemRevealBorderBrushPointerOver}" />
                                    <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonForegroundPointerOver}" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>

                                <Storyboard>
                                    <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>

                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="RootGrid.(RevealBrush.State)" Value="Pressed" />
                                    <Setter Target="RootGrid.Background" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemRevealBackgroundPressed}" />
                                    <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemRevealBorderBrushPressed}" />
                                    <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonForegroundPressed}" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>

                                <Storyboard>
                                    <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>

                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="RootGrid.Background" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonRevealBackgroundDisabled}" />
                                    <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonRevealBorderBrushDisabled}" />
                                    <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonForegroundDisabled}" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

**Usage**

```
<Button
    VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
    Click="Button_Click"
    Content="Connect"
    Style="{ThemeResource CudtomButtonRevealStyle}" />
```

Comment: if using tapped event, how to prevent middle click from pointer?

Comment: Do you means scroll wheel click? I'm afraid we can't prevent it, it is system level, for this scenario, we suggest use above custom reveal style.

Answer (score 1):

This is the **focus** problem. When you use a keyboard, you could use `Tab` to move focus to `Button`, so it fires the click event.

When you use a pointer, and press on the `Button`, `ListViewItem` is the first one to capture your click event, you can add a `Tapped` event to `ListViewItem` to prove it.

So If you insist want the `Button` to respond to your pointer, I think you can remove the `ListViewItem`.

```
   <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
        <Grid Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget="True">
            Add button content here
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
```